# Exclude Angluar2 route from Spring Web MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, angular, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that has a few views set up. I also have bundled an Angular2 app. When I load the Angular2 app, all works fine, however, when I try to deep link to a route within the application, Spring MVC is intercepting the call, failing to find an associated view and returning the error page.

http://localhost:8080/index.html will load the Angular2 application which then re-writes the URL to be just http://localhost:8080/. If I then navigate to the route I want e.g. http://localhost:8080/invite/12345, then the route loads and works as expected. Hitting http://localhost:8080/invite/12345 directly returns the standard Spring MVC error page.

However, if I run the Angular2 app as a standalone application (not served up by spring-boot), then hitting that link directly works as expected. it loads the index.html, fires the route and shows me the data I want.

How can I, via Java configuration, tell Spring to ignore the `/invite/**` path (and other paths too as my Angular2 app grows) so I can deep-link to routes within my Angular2 application. Here's the current Java configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
        registry.addViewController("/success").setViewName("success");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

This project is inheriting from spring-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? What would it return, then? How about making all of the links to return the same result (page)?

Comment: @acdcjunior - I have a number of Spring Web MVC views configured that still need to work, but when I hit the `/invite/**` path, that path is actually controlled by the Angular 2 app that's bundled so I want that path not to be processed by Spring MVC.

Comment: Suppose the root of the Angular2 app is at `/invite/`. If that's the case, then a request to that URL returns a view that contains the angular2 app, would you agree? If that's the case, just make any request to `/invite/**` point to that same view (without rewriting the URL, so angular knows where it is exactly). What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I got round this in the end was to link directly to the index.html page so that it forced the angular2 app to load e.g.:

http://localhost:8080/index.html/#/invite/12345

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer, I config like this and it's worked.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Override
public String index()
{
    return "index";
}

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login()
{
    return "redirect:/#/login";
}
```

So we can access to localhost:8080/angular-app/login/ without 404 error.